# Decrypt String with Crypto

Tags: playframework-2.0

the Play Framework 2.0 provides the lib **Crypto**, see code: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/Crypto.scala

So If want to sign a value I can use:

```
Crypto.sign(username);
```

But how to decrypt the username again? There is not method **unsign** or **decrypt**? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API is for creating a signature, a SHA1 hash (as you can see in the code you link to). The purpose of that is not to be reversible (unsigned) but to be used as verification of authenticity.

For example, if you have signed an authentication token, you can make sure that it had not been tampered with by checking that `Crypto.sign(token) == tokenSignature`.

If you want encryption and decryption, check out `Crypto.encryptAES`/`Crypto.decryptAES` (added in Play 2.1).

Comment: what the benefit of it , we can also check by`myString=password`

Comment: Please note that Crypto.encryptAES is vulnerable to malleability attacks unless it is combined with a MAC for authentication, because it uses AES-CTR.  What you probably want is AES-GCM.  `Crypto` will be deprecated in 2.5.x and there's a migration guide for moving off it: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CryptoMigration25

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do? You only sign a value to ensure that it wasn't altered. The point is that you cannot "unsign" it easily.

If you want to encrypt and decrypt a value within your app, you have to use an encryption algorithm from [`javax.crypto`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I want to decrypt a username and password, and in Play! 1.2.4 I have used the Crypto class for that.. And then at request time I want to show the username and password, so I need to decrypt it again. But I understand that I need to use additional classes for this purpose...

Answer (score 1):

If you need encrypt/decrypt functionality you can try to add http://www.jasypt.org/.

org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor allows the user to encrypt and decrypt text data using a     normal-strength algorithm. In order to be able to encrypt and decrypt.

Than you can do something like this:

```
...
BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
textEncryptor.setPassword(myEncryptionPassword);
...
String myEncryptedText = textEncryptor.encrypt(myText);
String plainText = textEncryptor.decrypt(myEncryptedText);
...
```

Comment: Yes, indeed I came across this one :-). And I will try to use it in my project, thanks anyway for sharing.

Comment: I wouldn't use jasypt, because it invents its own crypto: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/65240